# What happens to the no-longer-referenced chunk when I reassign half of a linked list?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have successfully implemented a custom numeric base system in Rust via linked lists called [digits](https://github.com/danielpclark/digits).

```
pub struct Digits<'a> {
    mapping: &'a BaseCustom<char>,
    digit: u64,
    left: Option<Box<Digits<'a>>>,
}
```

I've declared a lifetime on the linked list struct and linked it directly to an instance of `BaseCustom`. When I reassign half of the linked list, what happens to the unreferenced chunk which still has its lifetime associated with the `BaseCustom` mapping?

For example, I have a linked list that looks like "hello" (I'll use left to right for this example and not right to left as in my project)

```
h -> e -> l -> l -> o
```

Then I reassign the linked list reference from **`e`** to a different set of characters.

```
h -> e    l -> l -> o
      \
       -> d -> g-> e
```

Now that the code is no longer using the "llo" of hello, does that memory automatically get freed?  Does the fact that each character instance here have a reference to `BaseCustom`'s lifetime mean that the memory is held on to until the program ends?

I know Rust doesn't have or use a garbage collector so the lifetime reference to `BaseCustom` confuses me here.  Is it stating that the items must live as long as `BaseCustom`?  Or is it that they get freed up at some point but `BaseCustom` must outlive them?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the fact that each character instance here have a reference to `BaseCustom`'s lifetime mean that the memory is held on to until the program ends?

[Say it with me](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotation-syntax):

> Lifetime annotations don’t change how long any of the references involved live

[Or the jargon version you might see elsewhere](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/lifetimes.html):

> Lifetimes are *descriptive*, not *prescriptive*.

The fact that there are lifetimes present does not change the behavior of your code.

When you overwrite `left` with a new value, nothing knows about the old value so it must be dropped. In this case, that means a value of type `Option<Box<Digits<'a>>>` is dropped. If it's a `Some`, this calls the destructor for `Box` which would in turn call the destructor for `Digits`, which will call the destructor for `mapping`, `digit`, and recursively for its own `left`.

What does dropping a reference or an integer *do*? Absolutely nothing.

> Is it stating that the items must live as long as `BaseCustom`? Or is it that they get freed up at some point but `BaseCustom` must outlive them?

The lifetime states that `Digits` may not outlive `BaseCustom`. This makes sense because it contains a reference to `BaseCustom`.

---

See also:

- [Do we need to manually create a destructor for a linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38147453/155423)

Comment: "Lifetimes are descriptive, not prescriptive." This should be in the book.

Comment: @red75prime click the link on "say it with me" to go to the book where it is :-)

Comment: @red75prime the second edition isn't quite as concise, but probably easier to understand. Added. :-)